# Unable to delete related media attachments with deleted post

Tags: php, attachments, wp-delete-post

I want to delete the post attachments too from the 'Media" panel once a custom post is deleted. The post itself gets deleted well, but its media still remains in the wordpress "media" panel:

Archive page:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['delete-btn'])) {

    $deletePost = $_POST['post-id'];

    wp_delete_post( $deletePost, true);
    do_action( 'delete_post', $_POST['post-id'] );
}
?>
```

Functions.php:

```
//delete all media attached with deleted post
    add_action( 'delete_post', 'delete_post_children' );

    function delete_post_children( $post_id )
    {
    wp_delete_attachment( $post_id );
};
//delete all media attached with deleted post end
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I think that this `do_action( 'delete_post', $_POST['post-id'] );` is not necessary, try commenting this line and tring again, also do a `print_r` to `$_POST` to check that all 
the properties exist and have the expected value

Comment: If you want to permanently delete an attachment, try setting the second parameter to true: `wp_delete_attachment( $post_id, true )`.